# ReactiveForm Switch Statement Cannot Be Compared to FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to use a switch statement to validate errors for my reactiveForm.

I display the error like this in my form:

```
<mat-error>{{errorMessage}}</mat-error>
```

And my plan is to validate the error like this, but it tells me that the type boolean can't be compared to "FormGroup". What's the best way to solve something like this?

```
errorValidation() {

let errorMessage = '';
const formMail = this.personForm.get('mail');

switch (formMail.hasError) {
  case 'required':
      {
          errorMessage = 'This field is required';
          break;
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`formMail.hasError` is returning a boolean not the string 'required'.

You can check for specific types of error by using `inputname.errors.minlength` or `inputname.errors.required` etc using if statements.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation